# Jumps in Distribution using np.random

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have written the following code which randomly selects a number between 0 and 1 from a uniform distribution and associates it with an 'LF' value based on certain conditions.

```
    df['RAND'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=df.index.size)

    conditions = [
        df['RAND'] >= (1 - 0.8062),
        (df['RAND'] < (1 - 0.8062)) & (df['RAND'] >= 0.1),
        (df['RAND'] < 0.1) & (df['RAND'] >= 0.05),
        (df['RAND'] < 0.05) & (df['RAND'] >= 0.025),
        (df['RAND'] < 0.025) & (df['RAND'] >= 0.0125),
        (df['RAND'] < 0.0125)
    ]
    choices = ['LF0', 'LF1', 'LF2', 'LF3', 'LF4', 'LF5']
    df['LF'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
    # print(df['LF'])
    print(df.pivot_table(index=df['LF'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0))
```

The problem I am having is that when I generate a pivot table, I notice there are 'jumps' in the distribution - that is, an 'LF' value is skipped. I've included a link to a picture of my output below, where the 'LF4' value is skipped:

[LF Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Gqq.png)

Could anybody explain this for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried this, and it worked fine.  I used 100,000 values and got `[80647,  9321,  5023,  2521,  1246,  1242]` as the counts.  Your sample size was probably too small, and you got "lucky."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, your sample size is just too small.  If you increase the number of random values, or run repeatedly, you should see that it works fine.

A tip: you have twice as many conditions as you need, because `np.select()` takes the first match.  So:

```
conditions = [
    df['RAND'] >= (1 - 0.8062),
    df['RAND'] >= 0.1,
    df['RAND'] >= 0.05,
    df['RAND'] >= 0.025,
    df['RAND'] >= 0.0125,
    df['RAND'] < 0.0125, # same as np.isfinite(), or True if no NANs
]
```

This does exactly the same thing as your code.