# Run simulation based on values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have written some code that simulates values in a pandas dataframe based on a number of conditions. I now want to run this code only for specific values in a column called `df['Use Type']`. I currently have the following:

```
def l_sim():
    n = 100
    for i in range(n)

       df['RAND'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=df.index.size)

       conditions = [df['RAND'] >= (1 - 0.8062), (df['RAND'] < (1 - 0.8062)) & (df['RAND'] >= 0.1),
                  (df['RAND'] < 0.1) & (df['RAND'] >= 0.05), (df['RAND'] < 0.05) &
                  (df['RAND'] >= 0.025), (df['RAND'] < 0.025) & (df['RAND'] >= 0.0125),
                  (df['RAND'] < 0.0125)]
       choices = ['L0', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'L5']
       df['L'] = np.select(conditions, choices)

       conditions = [df['L'] == 'L0', df['L'] == 'L1', df['L'] == 'L2', df['L'] == 'L3',
                  df['L'] == 'L4', df['L'] == 'L5']
       choices = [df['A'] * 0.02, df['A'] * 0.15, df['A'] * 0.20, df['A'] * 0.50,
               df['A'] * 1, df['A'] * 1]
       df['AL'] = np.select(conditions, choices)


 l_sim()
```

How would I be able to run this code only for rows which have `df.loc[df['Use Type'] == 'Commercial Property']`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you have a loop `for` in your code? It seems to be never used in the code you do

Comment: @Ben.T I get a different set of random numbers for each i in range(100) and hence different 'L' values for each row in my dataframe.

Comment: ok, but if at each loop you rewrite the 'L' values in the same column, then the one at the previous loop are erased. Same for the column AL, your code just overwrite this column too, not considering the previous loop

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to structure your code differently. But in general, you can use `df.apply` and a lambda function. This pattern:

```
df['L'] = df.apply(lambda row: l_sim(row), axis=1)
```

I would split your code into three functions, one for `df['L']`:

```
def l_logic():
    random_num = np.random.uniform(0, 1)
    conditions = [random_num >= (1 - 0.8062), (random_num < (1 - 0.8062)) & (random_num >= 0.1),
              (random_num < 0.1) & (random_num >= 0.05), (random_num < 0.05) &
              (random_num >= 0.025), (random_num < 0.025) & (random_num >= 0.0125),
              (random_num < 0.0125)]
    choices = ['L0', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'L5']
    L = np.select(conditions, choices)

    return L
```

One for `df['AL']`. Since you used `df[A]` before you assigned it I changed it to `some_number`.

```
def al_logic(row):
    some_number = 1

    conditions = [row['L'] == 'L0', row['L'] == 'L1', row['L'] == 'L2', row['L'] == 'L3', row['L'] == 'L4', row['L'] == 'L5']

    choices = [some_number * 0.02, some_number * 0.15, some_number * 0.20, some_number * 0.50, some_number * 1, some_number * 1]
    AL = np.select(conditions, choices)

    return AL
```

The third for the logic to only create values when `row['Use Type'] =='Commercial Property'`:

```
def l_sim(row):
    if row['Use Type'] == 'Commercial Property':
        if 'L' in row.index:
            return al_logic(row)
        else:
            return l_logic()
    else:
        return 'NaN'
```

To start it:

```
df['L'] = df.apply(lambda row: l_sim(row), axis=1)

df['AL'] = df.apply(lambda row: l_sim(row), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dataframe has at least two columns 'A' and 'Use Type' such as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Use Type':['Commercial Property']*3+['other']*2, 'A':1})
```

then by modifying your function by:

```
def l_sim(df,use_type=None):
    #check if you want to do it ont he whole datafrmae or a specific Use type
    if use_type:
        mask = df['Use Type'] == use_type
    else:
        mask = slice(None)
    # generete the random values
    df.loc[mask,'RAND'] = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=df[mask].index.size)
    # create conditions (same for both L and AL by the way)
    conditions = [ df['RAND'] >= (1 - 0.8062), (df['RAND'] >= 0.1), (df['RAND'] >= 0.05), 
                  (df['RAND'] >= 0.025), (df['RAND'] >= 0.0125), (df['RAND'] < 0.0125)]
    #choices for the column L and create the column
    choices_L = ['L0', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4', 'L5']
    df.loc[mask,'L'] = np.select(conditions, choices_L)[mask]
    #choices for the column AL and create the column
    choices_A = [df['A'] * 0.02, df['A'] * 0.15, df['A'] * 0.20, df['A'] * 0.50,
                 df['A'] * 1, df['A'] * 1]
    df.loc[mask,'AL'] = np.select(conditions, choices_A)[mask]
```

Then if you do:

```
l_sim(df,'Commercial Property')
print (df)
              Use Type  A      RAND    L    AL
0  Commercial Property  1  0.036593   L3  0.50
1  Commercial Property  1  0.114773   L1  0.15
2  Commercial Property  1  0.651873   L0  0.02
3                other  1       NaN  NaN   NaN
4                other  1       NaN  NaN   NaN
```

and

```
l_sim(df)
print (df)
              Use Type  A      RAND   L    AL
0  Commercial Property  1  0.123265  L1  0.15
1  Commercial Property  1  0.906185  L0  0.02
2  Commercial Property  1  0.107588  L1  0.15
3                other  1  0.434560  L0  0.02
4                other  1  0.304901  L0  0.02
```

I removed the loop `for` as I don't see the point and I simplify your `conditions` like in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53339852/9274732)  of your previous question